# PowerShell ScriptBlock and multiple functions

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, scriptblock

I have written the following code:

```
cls
function GetFoo() { 
    function GetBar() {
        $bar = "bar"
        $bar
    }

    $foo = "foo"
    $bar = GetBar
    $foo
    $bar
}


$cred = Get-Credential "firmwide\srabhi_adm"
$result = Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName localhost 
-ScriptBlock ${function:GetFoo}
Write-Host $result[0]
Write-Host $result[1]
```

It works but I don't want to define `GetBar` inside of `GetFoo`.

Can I do something like this?

```
cls
function GetBar() {
    $bar = "bar"
    $bar
}

function GetFoo() {     
    $foo = "foo"
    $bar = GetBar
    $foo
    $bar
}


$cred = Get-Credential "firmwide\srabhi_adm"
$result = Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName localhost 
-ScriptBlock ${function:GetFoo; function:GetBar; call GetFoo}
Write-Host $result[0]
Write-Host $result[1]
```

Basically I am selectively putting the functions which I want in the ScriptBlock and then calling one of them. This way I don't have to define function inside of function and I can construct the ScriptBlock by injecting the functions which I want to be a part of that ScriptBlock.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Invoke-Command` can only see what's inside `ScriptBlock`, it can't see functions definded outside. If you really want to - you can run everything in one line, like this:

```
$result = Invoke-Command  -ComputerName localhost  -ScriptBlock { function GetBar() { $bar = "bar"; $bar }; function GetFoo() { $foo = "foo"; $bar = GetBar; $foo;  $bar }; GetFoo }
```

But I personally would advise you to save functions in script and call `Invoke-Command` with `-FilePath` parameter, like this:

```
$result = Invoke-Command  -ComputerName localhost  -FilePath "\1.ps1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently got this working:

```
function GetBar() {
    $bar = "bar"
    $bar
}

function GetFoo() {     
    $foo = "foo"
    $bar = GetBar
    $foo
    $bar
}

$NewScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("function GetBar() { ${function:GetBar} } function GetFoo() { ${function:GetFoo} } GetFoo")
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock $NewScriptBlock
```

Alternatively you can spare a line using:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create("function GetBar() { ${function:GetBar} } function GetFoo() { ${function:GetFoo} } GetFoo"))
```

The trick is that the Create method of the ScriptBlock class adds the code *inside* the functions, but not the header and final bracket. You need to add that yourself, plus the final invoke.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I hope it helps someone.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()
$barScriptBlock = {
    function GetBar() {
        $bar = "bar"
        $bar
    }
}
$fooScriptBlock = {
    function GetFoo() {     
        $foo = "foo"
        $bar = GetBar
        $foo
        $bar
    }
}
# Concatenate all functions into a script block; add a parameter for extra credit.
$scriptBlockString = @"
param(`$hello)
$($barScriptBlock.ToString())
$($fooScriptBlock.ToString())
`$hello
GetFoo
"@
Write-Verbose $scriptBlockString
# Convert combined string to script block.
$finalScriptBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create($scriptBlockString)
# Run synchronously, passing runtime parameter.
$result = & $finalScriptBlock "Hola"
# (Async results would not be reiably accessed here yet.)
Write-Host $result[0]
Write-Host $result[1]
Write-Host $result[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [Joe Zamora's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100945/powershell-scriptblock-and-multiple-functions/61977716#61977716), here's a command that I think fits the question better:

```
$result = Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create("${function:GetFoo}; ${function:GetBar}; GetFoo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
#get my script path
$this_Script = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.path

#get get all my location functions and filters
$this_functions = Get-Item FUNCTION:\* | Where-Object { $_.ScriptBlock.File -eq $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath( $this_Script  ) }

$mything | ForeachObject -Parallel {
    
    $this_functions = $using:this_functions


    $this_functions | Foreach-Object {  
        #create function scriptblocks
        $sb = "$($_.CommandType) $($_.name) {$($_.ScriptBlock) }" ; 
    
        Invoke-Expression $sb ;
    }
}
```

The above only works in in Pwsh Core.