# Calling function from remote script block

Tags: powershell

My powershell script is as below. I try to zip a folder at remote machine. I don't want to put Zip function inside `ScriptBlock` because it will be used in other parts of the script.

```
function Zip{  
    param([string]$sourceFolder, [string]$targetFile)  
    #zipping   
}  

$backupScript = {  
    param([string]$appPath,[string]$backupFile)      
    If (Test-Path $backupFile){ Remove-Item $backupFile }  
    #do other tasks      
    $function:Zip $appPath $backupFile  
}  

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machineName -ScriptBlock $backupScript -Args $appPath,$backupFile
```

In `$backupScript`, it is giving error in $function:Zip line:

> *+     $function:Zip $appPath $backupFile
>
>   +                   ~~~~~~~~
>   Unexpected token '$appPath' in expression or statement.*

Answer (score 2):

You have to refer to arguments in a scriptblock like:

```
$backupScript = {  
    param([string]$appPath,[string]$backupFile)      
    If (Test-Path $backupFile){ Remove-Item $backupFile }  
    #do other tasks      
    $function:Zip $args[0] $args[1]  
}  
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machineName -ScriptBlock $backupScript -Args       $appPath,$backupFile
```

Also, the function will not be known by the target machine, you'll have to define it within the script-block or pass it to the machine.

Here is an example:
[How do I include a locally defined function when using PowerShell's Invoke-Command for remoting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367367/how-do-i-include-a-locally-defined-function-when-using-powershells-invoke-comma)

This example puts it in your perspective:
[PowerShell ScriptBlock and multiple functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100945/powershell-scriptblock-and-multiple-functions)

Answer (score 0):

I would find some way of getting your shared functions onto your server.  We have a standard share on all our servers where we deploy common code.  When we run code remotely, that code can then reference and use the shared code.